# C#: more elegant way to build a HashSet from the OrderedDictionary.Keys?

Tags: c#, hashset, ordereddictionary

I have an `OrderedDictionary d` filled with string keys (+ objects as the value). I need to copy the dictionary keys to a `HashSet<string> hs`.

I am doing it now like this:

```
OrderedDictionary d = new OrderedDictionary();
// ... filling d ...

HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (string item in d.Keys)
    hs.Add(item);
```

I know there is `.CopyTo()` method of the dictionary to fill the array of strings. Is there any more elegant way to copy the keys also to a `HashSet`?

**Update:** It seems that the suggested `new HashSet<string>(d.Keys.Cast<string>());` does not work for the `OrderedDictionary`. The compiler (VS2019 Community Ed.) says...

Error    CS1929  'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast(EnumerableRowCollection)' requires a receiver of type 'EnumerableRowCollection'

[image: at tooltip]

**Update 2:** The above Update works when `using System.Linq;` is added.

Comment: Consider setting capacity beforehand - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Int32_ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - use the constructor, casting the `Keys` property sequence accordingly:

```cs
var hs = new HashSet<string>(d.Keys.Cast<string>());
```

(As ever with LINQ, make sure you have a `using` directive for the `System.Linq` namespace.)

Comment: Thanks, Jon, but it seems that the `OrderedDictionary.Keys` does not support the `.Cast` as the `Dictionary<,>.Keys` does.

Comment: @pepr According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.keys?view=net-5.0) it should be just fine

Comment: @pepr: What do you mean by "does not support"? I can't see why it wouldn't... https://gist.github.com/jskeet/bd70e6a01823b5cdd3e4e2b2ed0bcca3 builds, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have added Update to the question with the explanation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ah, yes. The Linq have to be used.